# Proper openssl_encrypt and openssl_decrypt

Tags: php, encryption, openssl

I'm having a few issues with `openssl_*` functions in `PHP`:

For some reason the `PHP` page (http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) says that the `$options` parameter can be one of these `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING`

When I encrypt data using `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` however it shows blank fields.

```
$passphrase = md5( 'lolhaha' );
$iv                 = md5( 'cheese' );

$enc = openssl_encrypt( "Hello World!", "aes-256-cbc", $passphrase, OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv );
echo $enc . "{ENC}";

echo ' --------- ';

$dec = openssl_decrypt( $enc, "aes-256-cbc", $passphrase, OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv );
echo $dec . "{DEC}";
```

However, if I use `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` it works fine. Now, when using `false` in that field it works too, but returns `base64` is this because i'm using an older version of `PHP` maybe and it's still using `bool $raw_output`? Is `int $option OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` the same as `bool $raw_output false`?

Also, I'm getting the message that my `IV` is too long for the cipher i'm using; it should be 16 bytes apparently. According to `OpenSSL` (https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/enc.html) the `$iv` and `$passphrase` (the `key` according to `biohazard` on `PHP` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php)) should be of hex-digit values, is `md5` proper for that? How many bytes can the `passphrase/key` be?

Errr, in other words, how do you use this encryption properly? //Confused

Comment: Try to ask one question per *eh* question, CakeSneer. If the IV is too long, I would try the raw MD5 output. For some reason everybody that uses PHP thinks that MD5 is some magic function to generate keys and IV's from passwords. IT'S NOT, use PBKDF2 or bcrypt instead.

Comment: The official `OpenSSL` page states however that the `passphrase/key` has to be hex-digit. So, I was wondering if `md5()` is valid for that? For example `substr( md5( 'abc' ), 0, 16 )`

Comment: MD5 produces 16-byte hashes. You're using AES-256, so you need a 32-byte key. You should probably use SHA-256 to get the 32-byte `passphrase` string; or use a PBKDF to generate the 32-bytes of keying material.

Comment: I think you meant SHA-512 with raw data (binary). Works like a charm, appending a single byte after SHA-512 (raw data) won't however. :)

Comment: OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING turns off all padding (you have to do your own padding).  OPENSSL_RAW_DATA returns raw data to the caller instead of Base64 encoding it.

Answer (score 0):

> Errr, in other words, how do you use this encryption properly? //Confused

If you're looking for security, use [defuse/php-encryption](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) instead.

If you're looking to learn, [see how defuse/php-encryption encrypts messages](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption/blob/13fe6f8724b5bbf4e6492d0b2e46a5ea6a0b2316/src/Crypto.php#L386-L392) internally.

Generally, the OpenSSL extension gives you [too many options](https://paragonie.com/blog/2019/10/against-agility-in-cryptography-protocols). It's safe to use under expert supervision (unlike mcrypt), but it's still not a great developer experience.